# Simplify for C1 help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello I am a bit rusty on my math. The equation I have is:

$$fo={1\over 2π\sqrt{L((C_1C_2)/(C_1+C_2))}}$$

I have to solve for C1 with a known fo. When I tried I got:

$$
(((1/fo)/(2⋅π)^2)⋅L⋅C2) / C2 = C1
$$

I do not believe I did this right. Can someone better take me through it. I get confused when it comes down to (C1⋅C2/C1+C2) on one side.

Thank you.

Comment: fo=1/(2⋅π⋅√(L⋅(C1⋅C2/C1+C2))

Comment: its both. C1 times C2 divided by C1 plus C2. That is than multiplied by L. All of that is square rooted. After the square root it is than multiplied by 2 pie. Lastly 1 is divided by that number.

Comment: I know everything but C1. I am trying to solve for C1.

Comment: Yes, Sorry I am new to the site.

Comment: This question contains an attempt at the problem. The attempt is  mistaken, but shows progress, for example the factors of $L$ and $2\pi$ are both correct. It's missing latex formatting, but this contributor is new to the site. The question also had other problems with parentheses missing. However, this question was not "missing context". Since it's a very simple problem and hopefully OP is happy with the current answer, I won't vote to reopen. But it is surprising that five people voted to close this as missing context. The issue seems to be that the problem involves only simple algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$fo={1\over 2π\sqrt{L((C_1C_2)/(C_1+C_2))}}$$
then
$$
{C_1C_2\over C_1+C_2}={1\over L(2\pi fo)^2}
$$
is OK as in your proposed answer. Let $$q={1\over L(2\pi fo)^2}$$
then
$$
C_1 C_2=q(C_1+C_2)
$$
which we can rearrange to
$$
C_1(C_2-q)=qC_2
$$
so
$$
C_1={q C_2\over C_2 - q}={C_2\over C_2/q-1}={C_2\over L(2\pi fo)^2 C_2 - 1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, It seems simple when done like this but I was at a loss.